# Prove $(A^TA + \gamma I)x = b$ is unique

Tags: linear-algebra

The goal is to prove or disprove the following:

The solution to $(A^TA+\gamma I)x = b$ is unique for any $\gamma > 0$

Any hints for helping me solve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Show $det[\gamma I + A^T A] \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1: It suffices to show that $A^\top A + \gamma I$ is invertible.

Hint 2: What are the eigenvalues of $A^\top A + \gamma I$? What do eigenvalues have to do with invertibility?

Hint 3: It may be helpful to remember that $A^\top A$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: So we know that $x^T(A^TA + \gamma I)x \geq 0$ and so for $x$ an eigenvector, $x^T \lambda x \geq 0$. But all this shows me is that $\lambda \geq 0$, right? And I want to prove that all of the $\lambda$ are strictly greater than 0.

Comment: @user31415926 That's why the condition $\gamma > 0$ is important; the result does not hold for $\gamma = 0$.

Comment: I guess I'm just not sure where to go from this condition. I need to eliminate the case where $\lambda = 0$, but it brings me back to showing that the only solution to $(A^TA + \gamma I)x = 0$ is the zero vector. (Which I feel like is where we started)

Comment: @user31415926 Show that $x^\top (A^\top A + \gamma I)x > 0$. The fact that $\gamma > 0$ is crucial. Alternatively/equivalently, think about how the eigenvectors of $A^\top A + \gamma I$ are related to the eigenvectors of $A^\top A$.

Comment: Aha! I see it. It's because we can combine that x^Tx >0 and the positive semidefiniteness of A^TA right?

Comment: @user31415926 Yes that's right.